# mydiv keep coming after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a mydiv on my site which fades out after 10 seconds but when i refresh the page it 'll comes back again. I would need to know if i can add a code in .js to vanished completely for a visitor if they refresh the site again. I have tried cookie but so far but no success so all i need to know if i can add just a code in my js file to let that work?

here is what i have in .js which make the div disappears after 10 seconds.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#mydiv').fadeOut('fast');
}, 10000);
```

Comment: To stop `#mydiv` from appearing on reload or during subsequent visits, you will need to use cookies.

Comment: When you reload the page, all changes made to it prior the reload are discarded, and the entire DOM is reconstructed based on the new response. It will behave as if your fade function is never called. You need to add some code which will check on page load if it is appropriate to show `#mydiv`, based on a cookie, session, or other persistent source

Comment: HTML5 localStorage could be an option. http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'document.referrer'` property of page to see if the last page was this page or not. If it was, don't display the `div`. That's the best I can think of.

`'document.referrer'` gives you the url of the page which linked to your page.